# PHP Loop over txt file delete line after output

Tags: php

I have a php script where I am looping over all the lines in a text file. How can delete the line after it was read, so by the end of the script all of the lines which have been output will be deleted from the file...

```
$file = $dataDoc['file'];
if(is_file($file)){
     $contents = file($file);
     foreach($contents as $line) {
        echo $line . "\n";
        // Delete line here and keep looping over the rest of the lines...
     }
}
```

Comment: You mean - delete line from a file?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple solution can be:

```
$contents = file($file);
foreach($contents as &$line) {   // add `&` to modify source line
    echo $line . "\n";

    if (/*Some case is true*/) {
        $line = null;            // unset a line if needed
    }
}

// lines that are NULL will not be written to a file
$writeRes = file_put_contents($file, $contents);
```

Comment: The question is, what is this overhead good for? That way, you can just store an empty file in the end. If the delete after reading is meant to create some kind of backup in case of an error to prevent a duplicate computation, this does not help at all

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = $dataDoc['file'];
if(is_file($file)){
     $contents = file($file);
     foreach($contents as $i => $line) {
        echo $line . "\n";
        unset($contents[$i]);
        fopen($file, 'w');
        fwrite(implode('\n', $contents));
        fclose($file);
     }
}
```

Every line you're reading in the file you're removing from the $contents array, then rewriting the file without that line.  This isn't very efficient but is just one way to do it.